# How to fetch everything between the first "-" & third "-" in php?

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I have a pretty url link: 
*www.abcd.com/Topic-V-CNHVNTNCHUUINP-Gangulys-waving-jersey-at-Lords-or-Dhonis-six-to-win-the-world-cup---Which-was-the-biggest-winning-moment-in-Indian-cricket-history-Sourav-Ganguly-Mahendra-Singh-Dhoni*

I want to fetch only "V-CNHVNTNCHUUINP". The code which i wrote isn't working:

```
$value = "www.abcd.com/Topic-V-CNHVNTNCHUUINP-Gangulys-waving-jersey-at-Lords-or-Dhonis-six-to-win-the-world-cup---Which-was-the-biggest-winning-moment-in-Indian-cricket-history-Sourav-Ganguly-Mahendra-Singh-Dhoni";

$newstr = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, '-', strpos($value, '-')+3));
$afterunderscore = substr($newstr, strpos($newstr, "-") + 1);
```

This is fetching me : V-CNHVNTNCHUUINP.

But when testing with link:
*www.abcd.com/Topic-HN-CNHVNTNCHWTSSW-Sharukh-Khan-or-Salman-Khan---Who-is-the-biggest-superstar-of-bollywood*

The result i get is: HN.

**GOAL:** Fetch **HN-CNHVNTNCHWTSSW** When link is *www.abcd.com/Topic-HN-CNHVNTNCHWTSSW-Sharukh-Khan-or-Salman-Khan---Who-is-the-biggest-superstar-of-bollywood*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work as expected:

Function `strposX` will return position of `$number` appearance of `$needle` in `$haystack`. Then just use `substr` to select wanted part of string stored in `$value` variable.

```
function strposX($haystack, $needle, $number) {
    preg_match_all("/$needle/", utf8_decode($haystack), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    return $matches[0][$number-1][1];
}

$value = "www.abcd.com/Topic-HN-CNHVNTNCHWTSSW-Sharukh-Khan-or-Salman-Khan---Who-is-the-biggest-superstar-of-bollywood";

$start = min(strposX($value, '-', 1), strposX($value, '-', 3));
$length = abs(strposX($value, '-', 1) - strposX($value, '-', 3));

echo substr($value, $start + 1, $length - 1);
```

**Output:**

```
HN-CNHVNTNCHWTSSW
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expression to get the match:

```
$value = "www.abcd.com/Topic-HN-CNHVNTNCHWTSSW-Sharukh-Khan-or-Salman-Khan---Who-is-the-biggest-superstar-of-bollywood";

// will account for "V-CNHVNTNCHUUINP" and "HN-CNHVNTNCHWTSSW"
$pattern = "/Topic-([A-Z]+-[A-Z]+)-/";
$matches = [];

preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);

if (isset($matches[1])) {
    // we got a match
    echo $matches[1]; // prints "HN-CNHVNTNCHWTSSW"
}
```